# Condition fulfilled but if-statement won't trigger?

Tags: if-statement, button, javafx, key-events

I have a scene, and this fully functional button called btnRemove,

```
Button btnRemove = new Button("Remove");
btnRemove.setMinWidth(85);

btnRemove.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        if(mediaTable.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){
        txtNotification.setText("Please select an item from the list");
        }
        else{
        medium.remove(mediaTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
    }
});
```

and now I want to make it so that when the *DELETE*-key is pressed, the btnRemove button is triggered and removes the item in focus/the selected element.

Here's the code:

```
    scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getCode());
            if("DELETE".equals(event.getCode())) {
                System.out.println("ATTEMPT ----");
                btnRemove.fire();
            }
        }
    });
```

When I run it, the console outputs *DELETE* whenever I press *DELETE*, but it doesn't output "*ATTEMPT ----*" after that.

I don't see any reason why it shouldn't trigger

What gives??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare a `KeyCode` to a `String`. Change the condition to -

```
if (KeyCode.DELETE == event.getCode()) { ... }
```

What you are seeing in the first `println` is the KeyCode's toString, which apparently returns it's name.